# Last row always returns false?

Tags: php, mysql

This works well, except that the last row always returns false. I've use this multiple times within my site and no matter what query I run, the last row always returns false instead of the data in the last row.

So if I have a query that should return 2 rows, it returns 1 row and false. I'm not really sure why.

```
function query2array($query, $sql_con) {
    $result = mysql_query($query,$sql_con); 

    if(!$result) {
        return false;
    } 
    else if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //set entire result to array
        while($arr_data[] = mysql_fetch_array($result));

        var_dump($arr_data);        

        if(count($arr_data) > 0) {
            return $arr_data;
        }
    }

    return false; 
}
```

I'm new to PHP and I've read the documentation on mysql_fetch_array and just can't seem to figure out what's going wrong here. (I also know that I should be using mysqli, but I picked up on a site developed by someone else)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))$arr_data[] = $row;
```

The reason of such behaviour is you appending `mysql_fetch_array()` result to array  without checking if it successfully retrieved.

As of [`manual`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   FALSE if there are no more rows.

---

**NOTICE:** [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (*mysql**_ functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (*mysqli**_ functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: @Nonear , also I wolud like to note, that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Either way, good luck.